# Align div elements next and under each other

Tags: css, html

i want to align 4 div boxes so that they are in a 2x2 layout like this

```
1 2
3 4
```

My code looks like this

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;float:left;">    DIV 1    </div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px;float:left;">    DIV 2    </div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px;clear:left;">    DIV 3    </div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px;float:left;">    DIV 4    </div>
```

which produces the following layout:

```
1 2
3
4
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: With the latest advancements, you could use Flexbox for this https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Give all of them `float: left`, then wrap them in a container just wide enough to fit 2 of them, so that the other two gets pushed down. For example,

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 600px;
}

#container div {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

---

**Edit:** If you want more `div`s inside the ones you already got, then you can always apply the same technique to the children, like

```
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div>Inner Div 1</div>
    <div>Inner Div 2</div>
    <div>Inner Div 3</div>
    <div>Inner Div 4</div>
  </div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Then with CSS, use this additional style:

```
#container div div {
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: If i'm using other DIVs inside my DIV1,DIV2,.. would this also work ? e.g. <div> DIV1 <div>OtherElements</div></div>... ??

Comment: @Tim. Updated the answer - in short, yes

Answer (score 13):

replace `<div style="width:300px;height:300px;clear:left;">`  of **Div 3** with `<div style="width:300px;height:300px; clear:both; float:left">`

full html

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;float:left;">
    DIV 1
</div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px;float:left;">
    DIV 2
</div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px; clear:both; float:left">
   DIV 3
</div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px;float:left;">
   DIV 4
</div>
```

Comment: always use container div as described by Yi Jiang for avoiding collapses with other html parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using this:

```
<body style="width:600px; height:600px;">
<div id="container">
    <div style="width:50%; height:50%;float:left;">
    DIV 1
</div>

    <div style="width:50%; height:50%;float:left;">
    DIV 2
</div>

    <div style="width:50%; height:50%; float:left;">
    DIV 3
</div>
    <div style="width:50%; height:50%;float:left;">
    DIV 4
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Obviously by placing the style information in to a CSS file rather than in the HTML.

I would try to avoid setting the width & height to a specific size unless you simply cannot avoid it.  It causes lots of issues when viewed on different browsers at different resolutions.

Comment: "It causes lots of issues when viewed on different browsers at different resolutions. " Mind commenting on this? I don't think that's ever the case unless you forget the reset script. Also, you left a `clear: both` on the third `div` ;)

Comment: @Yi Jiang - oops, thanks.  I have just been through a site which had every width & height set as `px` which worked but only at a specific resolution. I went through and changed then to `%` and the pages render much better across different resolutions. Just something that I have recently encountered.  maybe it was a one off and it was just a bad design in the first place.

Comment: It probably is - frameworks like 960gs use ridiculously precise `px` values that all add up perfectly to conform to the grid, and it all renders fine across all browsers and resolutions